# Rails 3 strftime week number not ISO 8601 compliant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, iso

The API dock states:
%U - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Sunday.  (00..53)
%W - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Monday.  (00..53)
ISO 8601 states that the first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday.
2013 starts on a Tuesday. Thus week 1 is that which starts with December 31, 2012 as week 1 (for %W)

Code:

```
my_date_variable.strftime("%W").to_i
```

is returning week # 1 as that starting January 7, 2013.  Does not match what ISO 8601 would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems what you want is `%V` which is supported by ruby [`Date#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).

`> Date.parse("December 31, 2012").strftime("%V") => "01"`

Comment: By gosh, you're right! I hooked up to the week number directives definition, flying over the ISO 8601 ones!